# Solve $(x^2-5x+5)^{x^2+4x-60}=1$-Missing Solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, logarithms

Problem:
$$(x^2-5x+5)^{x^2+4x-60}=1$$

Attempt:

Taking logs on both sides:
$$(x^2+4x-60)\ln(x^2-5x+5)=0$$

Yields 4 solutions:
$$[1]: x^2+4x-60=(x+10)(x-6)=0 \implies x=-10,6$$
$$[2]: x^2-5x+5=1 \implies (x-4)(x-1)=0 \implies x=4,1$$

I'm missing one more solution. What am I missing?

Comment: Well, $(-1)^n=1$ if $n$ is even...

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having the power equal $1$ offers a big clue.

When $a^b=1$ in real variables, we must have one of the following:

- $b=0$. Depending on the definition of exponentiation one uses it may be necessary to check that $a\not=0$.
- $a=1$. Good for any value of $b$.
- $a=-1,b= \text{ an even integer}$. Depending on how you define powers with rational exponents you may also allow $b$ to be an even integer divided by an odd one, like $4/3$, but in this problem this case will give integer exponents. Be sure to allow both signs for $b$ here.

Work through these three cases with $a=x^2-5x+5,b=x^2+4x-60$ and tell us what you get.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple and basic method for this is

1. a^0=1
2. 1^a=1

Now by this idea you can see that may x2+4x-60 = 0
and may x2-5x+5 = 0
Now find this roots of x and that would be your solutions.

Comment: Unfortunately this misses the solution the OP wanted. You need to add the case where the base is $-1$ and the exponent either an even integer of (with some definitions of exponenentiation) an even integer divided by an odd one. See my answer.

Comment: @OscarLanzi ooh yes